# ayuda sobre arrays en Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script

Necesito enviar un mensaje de recordatorio a ciertos destinatarios de correo, tengo la siguiente estructura

```
function recordatorio () {
    var asunto      = "Recordatorio de felicitación";   
    var nombrebuzon = "Comunicación Global Engineering Mexico";
    var me          = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var Mensaje = "Buen día:<br><p>Les recuerdo que el día <b>" + (day+1) + " de "+ nameMonth +"</b> será el cumpleaños de <b>" + rNames + "</b>,"+
                  " por lo que sugerimos una felicitación personal.<p>"+
                  "<br>Para reforzar esta iniciativa <b>Comunicacion Global Engineering Mexico</b> le enviará al festejado(a) una postal de cumpleaños con la firma de la dirección.<br><br>Atentamente<br>"+
                  "<b>Comunicación Global Engineering Mexico<br>Strategy & Control</b>"+     
                  "<br>";


        Logger.log("Procesando recordatorio de Felicitacion para: " + remminderMailChief);

        GmailApp.sendEmail(remminderMailChief,asunto, "", {htmlBody: Mensaje, name: nombrebuzon, from: me});
        Utilities.sleep(1000); 

}
```

**Donde:**
"rNames" es un arreglo o lista con nombres separados por comas

```
[Carlos Alberto Ortiz , Miguel Flores García]
```

"remminderMailChief" es un arreglo o lista de correos separados por comas

```
[blablabla_1@gmail.com, blablabla_2@gmail.com]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mandar un correo a blablabla_1@gmail.com cambiándole en el Mensaje rName = "Carlos Alberto Ortiz" y de igual forma mandar un correo al segundo correo blablabla_2@gmail.com cambiándole en el Mensaje rName = "Miguel Flores García"

¿Cómo le hago para que se envíen de forma independiente?
    osea que al correo blablabla_1@gmail.com le llegue el mensaje pero con el nombre de "Carlos Alberto Ortiz" y al segundo correo el otro nombre.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Víctor!, realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Es **muy importante leer [ask]** que te brinda información de como realizar una pregunta en el sitio, realiza tu pregunta de acuerdo a este documento y obtendrás muy buenas respuestas!, saludos.

Comment: Hola Rubén, gracias por responder, ya solucioné el problema, mil gracias por tu apoyo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo este código que he probado y funciona perfectamente.

Todos los detalles están comentados en el mismo código.

Espero te sirva:

```
function doGmail() {

     /*Calcular la cuota de mensajes disponibles*/
      var intEMailQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
      var arrNombres=["Carlos Alberto Ortiz" , "Miguel Flores García"];  
      var arrEMails=["test1@example.com" , "test2@example.com"];

      /*Será más simple combinar los dos arrays*/
      var arrDatos = [];
      for(var n=0;n<arrNombres.length;n++){
            arrDatos.push({nombre:arrNombres[n],email:arrEMails[n]});
      }

      /*Calculamos total de emails a enviar, para verificar si tenemos cuota*/
      var intTotal=arrDatos.length;

      /*Verificamos si los mensajes a enviar no exceden la cuota*/
      if (intTotal<intEMailQuota){  
            arrDatos.forEach(function(element) {

                /*Variables para el envío*/
                var strNombre=element.nombre;
                var strEMail=element.email;
                var strAsunto='Prueba de mensaje';

                /*En este caso se toma el mensaje de un template perteneciente al mismo script*/
                var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();

                /*Lanzamos el envío*/
                MailApp.sendEmail({
                    to: strNombre + '<'+strEMail+'>',
                    subject: strAsunto,
                    htmlBody: htmlBody,
                });

           });

      } else {

            Logger.log('La cantidad de mensajes a enviar excede tu cuota diaria');            

      }  

}
```

Comment: Me ayudo mucho tu respuesta A.Cedano, mil gracias por tu apoyo, me diste buenas ideas para optimizar mi código, Saludos!

Comment: @VíctorHernández me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor lee: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**